# ssh tunnel in osx -- connection refused

Tags: macos, ssh

I'm trying to use an SSH tunnel for a web proxy. I've done this sort of thing before (for games.) I fire up firefox and tell it to proxy through localhost 12345 for everything. Then, `ssh user@host -L 12345:localhost:8080 -N`. When I try to use the browser, I get "connection refused." I enabled all the flags in sshd_config and restarted. No idea how to proceed. HALP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing up two commands.
Try to set Firefox to Socks5 at port 12345 and run:

```
ssh user@host -D 12345
```

[image]

From the SSH manual, 'man ssh':

```
-D [bind_address:]port
Specifies a local “dynamic” application-level port forwarding. ... Currently the SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 protocols are supported, and ssh will act as a SOCKS server.
```

Your command `user@host -L 12345:localhost:8080 -N` forwards your local port 12345 to the remote host's port 8080. This would only work if there would actually be a proxy running on port 8080 on your remote host.